# English usage: Every vs all?

Tags: word-usage

Today I was writing a simple message to be shown to the user whenever at least one field was not supplied.

> Every/All fields must be supplied.

I'm in doubt about the usage of Every vs All, which one do you think is the most appropriate here ?

Comment: "Every" is more appropriate if you want sure that no field remain excluded. Yes, it is strange; but English is not like  _logic_.

Comment: But _every_ is singular, so the plural on _fields_ has to go. Otherwise they're the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you can get it, you should read Zeno Vendler's article "**Each and Every, Any and All**," (originally published in Vol LXXI, no. 282 of *Mind*, April 1962; and reprinted in his 1967 book *Linguistics in Philosophy*).

Vendler goes through this set of English quantifiers and shows their differences and similarities.
I don't have my copy handy, so I'll just list a few differences here. These are all [universal quantifiers](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/logicguide.pdf), by the way.

- Although they are semantically plural, *each* and *every* are grammatically singular,
  while *all* is grammatically plural.

  - *Each student **has** a passing grade.*
  - *Every student **has** a passing grade.*
  - *All students **have** a passing grade.*
- *each* and *all* are subject to ***Quantifier-float***, but *every* isn't.
  (Note that Q-float with *each* requires a **plural** subject and verb, instead of singular.)

  - *Each student passed the course.* ~ *The students each passed the course.*
  - *All students passed the course.* ~ *The students all passed the course.*
  - *Every student passed the course.* ~ **The student(s) every passed the course.*
- as quantifiers, *each*, *every*, and *all* have quite different determiner constructions.

  - *all men, all the men, all of the men, all of them, all* ***N*** *of them* (*N > 2*)
  - *each man,* **each the men, each of the men, each of them, each one of them*
  - *every man,* **every the man,* **every of the man*, **every of them, every one of them.*

> ... and, as lagniappe, *all*, with ***N = 2***, is a quantifier and floats, but doesn't use *all*. Instead of **all two of them*, we say *both of them*; instead of **The twins all left* we say *The twins both left.*

Comment: Great answer. It is a lesson of grammar. Thank you +1

Comment: Unknown in British English: **Lagniappe**: *Something given over and above what is purchased, earned, etc., to make good measure or by way of gratuity.* (OED)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/621015/2085).

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of number agreement.  Either of these are acceptable:

> Every **field** must be supplied.
>
> All **fields** must be supplied.

You could also say ***each*** field must be supplied.

I must say that I disagree with *field* and *supplied* together.  The user is supplying information, not fields.  May I suggest:

> Each field/All fields must be **completed**?

Comment: I understand your point of view though "supplied" here is the most used expression, I guess.

Comment: I'd agreed with cornbread ninja. Supplied here indicates that the fields must be made available. For example, "When creating a form for your customers to fill out, make sure that all of these fields are supplied." However, I suppose you could say "All fields must be supplied with an answer."

Answer (score 0):

I was gonna say what cornbread said, but then I realized he already said it.  The word "supplied" is the reason for the ambiguity.  If "completed" doesn't float your boat you could always put "Each field must contain a response".