# Universal quantifiers

Tags: quantifiers, distributive-determiners

In the following statements all the individuals of a group are addressed for gratitude:

1. Gratitude is owed to *each* member of the group.
2. Gratitude is owed to *every* member of the group.
3. Gratitude is owed to *each and every* member of the group.

Hence to ask which are the distinctive qualities of *each*, *every* and *every and any* ?

Comment: A dictionary might help: it would also clarify the difference between *owe* and *own*.

Comment: No, a dictionary won't help. Quantifiers are part of grammar, not the lexicon. You might want to read Zeno Vendler's famous article "Each and Every, Any and All". (BTW, the frozen idiom is _each and every_, not _every and any_)

Comment: And a google for that article brought me [back here, where I'd already discussed it](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/73985/15299).

Comment: @John Lawler corrected each and every sentence, more gratitude owed :)

Comment: Exciting to discover floating quantifiers; may the etymology of each and every reveal more insight into usage ?

Comment: Probably not. Etymology is very mixed up when words become part of the grammar. All the English particles beginning with th-, for instance, come from the same Indo-European root, which was a pronoun even then. Likewise for the ones beginning with wh- and h-.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/621015/2085).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick inspection at the etymology of *each* and *every*, consider

- http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=each  and
- http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=every ,

reveals that *each* has its origins in Old English and is a short for *ever alike*, whereas *every* was originated in early 13c as a contraction of *each* and *ever*.

Following the sources depicted above, in Modern English, *every* conveys the same meaning as *each*, yet it strives for an emphasis on *each singular* item in a group.

Answer (score 1):

Following John's lead, I found this discussion of Vendler's *Each and Every, Any and All* (1962) in
[Madsen's blog](http://academiclogbook.blogspot.ca/2012/11/vendler-each-and-every-any-and-all-1962.html):

> Vendler describes the differences between *each*, *every*, and *all* in
>   terms of collective reference vs. individual reference. His theory is
>   that *all* is collective, while *each* and *every* are distributive.
>
> We thus have differences like
>
> - You can buy each of these items for $5 (*distributive*)
> - You can buy all of these items for $5 (*collective*)
>
> *Every*, on the other hand, can be seen as a quantification over all the
>   distributive attributions so that "*every* is between *each* and *all*" in
>   meaning (p. 77). We thus get — according to my intuitions — slightly
>   more ambiguous examples with *every*:
>
> - You can buy every one of these items for $5
>
> According to my intuition, this could lean towards both a collective
>   ($5 in total) and a distributive reading ($5 per item).

Comment: Even more ambiguous with a simple noun following: You can buy each book for $5 // You can buy every book for $5 // You can buy all books for $5.