# What adjective indicating number is understood when no adjective is used?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns

Take the following statement, when used within a conversation on Global Warming:

> Polar bears are dying in the North.

There is no adjective to describe the number of polar bears. According to normal English usage, should the modifier be assumed to be "some," "all," or some other quantifier?

Comment: Since "Polar bears" is plural, we know it's "at least two (possibly more)".

Comment: It is impossible to know exactly what the statement means. But if it is intended to mean 'all', the statement is unacceptable, a violation of the Gricean maxim of manner: 'all' would force this meaning and clarify as required. Pragmatically, 'a significant number' is probably intended, but this is subjective.

Comment: This negative vote should be  justified, the question is not, after all, without interest.

Comment: In the context of global warming, it probably means 'a larger proportion of the polar bear population than normal'.

Comment: ,,, and thus an extinction crisis is approaching. But this is in the realm of comprehension and logical/informed deduction.